# Session ID regeneration not working on windows

Tags: php, session

I have the following code which works fine under several linux flavors I have tried (Ubuntu, Debian 8, CentOS 7), however when I use it on windows, the regeneration fails without an error. `$duration` is a value in the class represented as `static $duration = 60 * SESSION_TIMEOUT;` where `SESSION_TIMEOUT` is a constant defined in a `config.inc.php` file (user setting).

```
session_start();
self::csrf(false);
if(self::verify(false) === true) {
    $_SESSION['expires']    =   time() + self::$duration;
}
session_regenerate_id(true);
$id = session_id();
session_write_close();
session_id($id);
session_start();
```

If I echo `$id` after the line `$id = session_id();` there is a value, however if I echo `session_id()` after the last `session_start()`, it is empty. (See [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php#87905) if you think this method is 'Dodgy' )

I do not know why this regeneration code is failing :

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
$id = session_id();

// one of the lines below this are causing session_id() to be blank
session_write_close();
session_id($id);
session_start();
```

Please assist me in identifying what is causing the new session to be blank when it should contain the new session id.

> session.save_path = 2;755;d:/server/www/127.0.0.1/sessions

Update:  I was able to find this in the log, however the interesting part is the session file is created with data.

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (2;755;d:/server/www/127.0.0.1/sessions) in Unknown on line 0

As requested, a sample of `$id` before calling `session_write_close()` (and subsequent code), is `9vdom0ghuqkvsdcnkjacurc6rf2n4fn1s1gvfva44okd15jdpm30`

**Update**:

After some more testing, I have traced the problem to be a bit more complex than stated above. The problem I initially had which I believed was a session regeneration issue, is more of a problem where session variables are not being stored.  I believe this is still related to session regeneration somewhat on windows, however I still am unable to pinpoint a fix, as this code works beautifully on Linux.

Here is the class (minified):

```
class session {

    static $duration = 60 * SESSION_TIMEOUT;

    public static function start() {
        session_start();
        self::csrf(false);
        if(self::verify(false) === true) {
            $_SESSION['expires']    =   time() + self::$duration;
        }
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        $id = session_id();
        session_write_close();
        session_id($id);
        session_start();
    }

    public static function csrf($new = false) {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['csrf']) || $new === true) {
            $_SESSION['csrf']       = sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(mt_rand(16,32)));
        }
        return $_SESSION['csrf'];
    }

}
```

The code used to call it, is rather complex (when it comes to determining when to generate a new csrf token), but below is my attempt to extract a chunk from my overall project to demonstrate the usage. The `login` code behind should suffice I believe to view the logic:

```
if( session::verify() === true ) {

    redirect();

} else {

    $error = '';
    $token = $_SESSION['csrf'];

    if ( !empty($_POST) ) {
        if ( isset($_POST['csrf']) ) {
            // check CSRF token and if match ti token stored in session
            $csrf       =   trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'csrf', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, array('flags' => FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH)));
            if($csrf != $_SESSION['csrf']) { session::destroy(); $error = 'CSRF Attack Detected'; }

            if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && empty($error) ) {
                // login validation code

                if($auth) {
                    // regenerate csrf token
                    $token = session::csrf(true);
                    session::create( $username );

                    // redirect back to application root
                    redirect();
                }
                $error = 'Invalid credentials';
            } else {
                if(empty($error)) { $error = 'Invalid credentials'; }
            }

            // user was not authenticated, regenerate csrf token to prevent form spam
            $token = session::csrf(true);

        } else {
            // CSRF token did not match stored token in session
            $error = 'CSRF Attack Detected';
        }
    }

}
```

The additional methods for my session class as used in the login code are as follows :

Update session data with user information.

```
public static function create($user) {
    $_SESSION['nonce']      =   sha1(microtime(true));
    $_SESSION['ip']         =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $_SESSION['agent']      =   sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $_SESSION['expires']    =   time() + self::$duration;
    $_SESSION['user']       =   $user;
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $id = session_id();
    session_write_close();
    session_id($id);
    session_start();
}
```

Verify posted information matches server session

```
public static function verify($destroy = false) {
    $valid = true;
    try {
        if( !isset($_SESSION['nonce']) ) { $valid = false; }
        if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) { $valid = false; }
        if( isset($_SESSION['ip']) ) { if($_SESSION['ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) { $valid = false; } } else { $valid = false; }
        if( isset($_SESSION['agent']) ) { if($_SESSION['agent'] != sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) { $valid = false; } } else { $valid = false; }
        if( isset($_SESSION['expires']) ) { if($_SESSION['expires'] <= time()) { $valid = false; } } else { $valid = false; }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $valid = false;
    }
    if($valid === false) {
        if(isset($_SESSION['nonce'])) { unset($_SESSION['nonce']); }
        if(isset($_SESSION['ip'])) { unset($_SESSION['ip']); }
        if(isset($_SESSION['agent'])) { unset($_SESSION['agent']); }
        if(isset($_SESSION['expires'])) { unset($_SESSION['expires']); }
        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) { unset($_SESSION['user']); }
        if($destroy === true) {
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

**Update**:

Narrowed this down by running a simple test :

```
// ensure sessions are writeable
if(!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    // try alternate session path
    $_session_save_path = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sessions';
    if(!is_writable($_session_save_path)) {
        echo "Can't write sessions"; exit;
    } else {
        session_save_path(
            $_session_save_path
        );
    }
}
```

Which echo's the result 'Can't write sessions' meaning it failed all methods to try and write data.

What is interesting here, is that no matter what I do (even setting the root of the drive to 'Everyone' with 'Full' permissions, all subfolders and files seem to have a permanent semi-shaded 'Read Only' checkbox.  Beyond this, `file_put_contents("hello.txt", "hello"); exit();` works in the root folder of my local site, but not from any subfolder below 2 directories deep -- even after assigning (and checking) permissions. (e.g.  d:\server\websites\127.0.0.1\htdocs\  works, but not d:\server\websites\127.0.0.1\htdocs\path1\path2\

**Update**:

Did some more troubleshooting, and the rabbit hole gets deeper. Ran a script to find what user PHP is running under to better assist in checking permissions:

```
echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();
```

which echo's  'Current script owner SYSTEM'

[image: SYSTEM permissions]

I followed up with this code :

```
$new = false;

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['csrf']) || $new === true) {
    $_SESSION['csrf']       = sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(mt_rand(16,32)));
}
session_regenerate_id(true);
$id = session_id();
session_write_close();
session_id($id);
session_start();
```

Which still failed. I did try something which finally worked, but I really don't feel comfortable with it as it involves not setting the security bits as documented in the php.ini file.

I changed :

```
session.save_path = "2;755;d:/server/www/127.0.0.1/sessions"
```

To

```
session.save_path = "d:/server/www/127.0.0.1/sessions"
```

And this works, however all the session files are now world accessible.

(Server is the same version of apache and php on all platforms configured with identical php.ini files, and server configuration files as close as possible)

Comment: Can you post the output of `print_r($id);` for the `$id` that you're passing to `session_id($id)` ?

Comment: @AlexW - the value for `$id` changes on each page load.  The purpose is to have a session that regenerates on each page load while keeping the information stored in tact.

Comment: What happens if you remove everything BUT `session_regenerate_id(true);` - I don't understand why the other code is even necessary as this would already generate a new ID and ensure the session is updated.

Comment: @skrilled - on the linux tests, I needed to call that else the data in the original session would be lost. Need to regenerate the id, save it, then load it with the new id that was just generated.  That was many hours of my life lost figuring that out -- and lots of google-fu.

Comment: Are you, by chance, using Internet Explorer?

Comment: @SamuelJackson I see - makes sense now

Comment: @AlexW - nope.  This issue occurs no matter which browser I use.  I know the problem you are implying all too well as that also took quite a while to overcome (where browser sessions would be destroyed or data lost for no apparent reason). I am still tracing this issue as we discuss here to see if I can resolve (of course), I noticed that the folder I specified for sessions has some weird permissions on it and windows is being very stubborn letting loose. Write access, no modify access, which is likely the cause.

Comment: Ok, I have traced my problem it's a bit more complex than I first thought. Updating code example to include the problem area.

Comment: Ok guys, I have added more information since the rabbit hole on this got deeper than expected. I have extracted and minimalized the relevant code.  Prior to all this, a `session::start()` is called.

Comment: I would recommend leaving it configured without the traditional Unix permissions.  You should be able to set permissions for the sessions folder(s) using the native Windows permissions dialog.  Just out of curiosity, which version of Windows is it? I've read that most configurations run under the `LocalSystem` user. I'm not sure if that is synonymous with `SYSTEM`.

Comment: @AlexW - I am running Windows 10.